# Nothing happens when I click on an element The code runs without error and I find the desired element But it did not click on the part I want

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

```
def check_follow_back(page,name_my_page):
driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{page}/')
time.sleep(2.5)
try :
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('_7UhW9    vy6Bb     MMzan   KV-D4           uL8Hv        T0kll ').click()
except:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('div._7UhW9    vy6Bb     MMzan   KV-D4           uL8Hv        T0kll ').click()
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_7UhW9    vy6Bb     MMzan   KV-D4           uL8Hv        T0kll "]').click()
print('click')
```

Here I tried to click on the part of Instagram that shows my following and after run Is shown print on terminal and it did not click on the part I want

Comment: You're never calling check_follow_back function. I also wouldn't trust those html classnames to be consistent

Comment: Can you provide html of the element you want to click please . Alternatively you can provide the url and element name do that we can look at it. I suspect the locator formed by you is not a link or button .. hence nothing is happening even if it click

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't have problems, but you never call your function.

Try to add:

```
func = check_follow_back(page,name_my_page)
```

with proper parameters

Comment: in main code i called the function my problem is that after find element Does not click